# Is every monosemiring an idempotent semiring?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, universal-algebra

Is every monosemiring an idempotent semiring?

To make my question clear, let me give definitions as follows:
A semiring $(R, +, .)$ is said to be monosemiring if $x.y= x+y$ for all $x, y$ in $R$. And idempotent semiring is the one in which $x.x= x=x+x$ for all $x$ in $R$. From this definition, we don't see that every monosemiring is an idempotent too. But there are some authors who define that monosemiring in an idempotent semiring satisfying the identity $x.y=x+y$ for all $x,y$ in $R$. So, from this definition, it seems like every monosemiring is an idempotent too.

Comment: If $R$ is a monosemiring, then $x = x+0 = x0 = x(0+0) = (x0) + (x0) = (x+0) + (x+0) = x+x$.

Comment: I still have a bit confusion  as " Does every monosemiring posses an identity"?  Because in general, some authors seem to ignore the requirement of identities in defining a semiring. here, in your answer the monosemiring R has the identity 0. would you  kindly clarify it please!

Comment: @gete Are you asking whether associativity and distributivity imply idempotency?  In that case the answer is "no"; there is a two-element counterexample.  - To make your question clear, *you* should define what you mean by monosemiring.  (Unless you want to ask what the customary definition or notation is. But it is my impression that these algebraic structures are not very popular.)

Comment: @Goldstern, thank you for your concern..
Let me try to make my question more clear..
A semiring (R,+,.) is said to be an idempotent semiring if x.x = x and x+x = x∀x ∈ R and the semiring (R,+,.) is said to be monosemiring if x.y = x+y ∀x,y ∈ R. There are some authors who treat every monosemiring as a particular class of idempotent semiring. My problem was that how to prove that every monosemiring is an idempotent semiring. I agree with the answer posed by Arturo Magidin, sir. But he has used identity 0 in his proof. (continued)

Comment: @Goldstern So, my next confusion is do we always assume the presence of identity in a monosemiring? because some algebraists ignores the requirement of identity elements in a semiring. Anyways, i am helped by your valuable inputs and hope for more such valuable suggestions. Thank you

Comment: To elaborate my comment above:  please make clear what *you* mean by semiring. Do *you* require a neutral element? Then the answer to the question in the title is "yes", by a famous theorem of Magidin.  If not, then the answer is no, and a counterexample is easy to find, as pointed out above.

Comment: General deﬁnition: A non-empty set (R,+,.) is said to be a semiring if (R,+) and (R,.) are commutative monoid and monoid, respectively. And “.” distributes over “ + ” from both left and right. In order to make this deﬁnition more inclusive, i am considering both (R,+) and (R,.) are semigroups rather than monoids. I am concluding that every monosemiring containing neutral element is idempotent, otherwise not as you pointed. Thank you for help..

Comment: @gete: When you say it is a "commutative monoid", then you **are** saying that it has a neutral element. Monoids *necessarily* have a neutral element. So saying "monosemiring containing a neutral element" is superfluous: under you definition they **must** contain a neutral element. Otherwise, what you need is to ask that $(R,+)$ be a *semigroup*, not a monoid.  So what you really want to say is that if the underlying additive structure is a monoid then... and if it is a semigroup but not a monoid then...